Deriving posterior distribution with explicit constants in closed form using Jacobian method compared to Bayes' rule



    
    
    Question on Bayesian Inference


    Deriving posterior distribution with explicit constants in closed form using Jacobian method compared to Bayes' rule

        I am working on a Bayesian inference problem with the following setup:
    

Given a transformation $ y_s = \frac{\rho_s}{r_s^4}x + z_s $, where $ z_s $ follows a standard normal distribution $ N(0,1) $.
The prior distribution for $ r_s $ is exponential with rate parameter $ \lambda $.
The likelihood function $ p_{y_s|r_s,x} $ is Gaussian with mean $ \alpha \frac{\rho_s}{r_s^4} $ and variance $ 1 $.


        I am interested in deriving the posterior distribution $ p_{r_s|y_s,x} $ for $ r_s $ explicitly with all constants in closed form. 
    

        My question is twofold:
    

Can I obtain the posterior distribution with explicit constants in closed form using the Jacobian method?
How does the solution obtained using the Jacobian method compare to the solution derived using Bayes' rule? Does one method lead to a closed form solution while the other does not?


        I appreciate any insights or assistance with this problem.
    

        Thank you.
    
